# Deplopment target in ios product in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, deployment, target, xcode8

I've developed a project and set its deployment target 10.3.  I then gave project to client who have iphone 7 plus and ios 10.3. This is working on his device. I gave the same product to another friend who have iphone 5 and ios version lower than 10. App is not running on iPhone 5. That device is saying that the app has minimum deployment target 10.3. I'm very much confused about deployment target. How could I manage those things for all devices and ios versions? Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iPhone 5C has the lower version of iOS than 10.3. Just change the deployment target of your project to lower version (version that has your iPhone 5C).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct.

Deployment target will tell iOS if the device has the minimum version to runs your app.
Answering your question:

> How could I manage those things for all devices and ios versions?

You can set your deployment target to i.e. iOS 8. But you have to develop your app using resources only available in iOS 8 or check in your code to present or not some newer resource.

The correct approach to do it is to handle version in your code using:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // use the feature only available in iOS 10
} else {
    // or use some work around
}
```

Then your deployment target can be lower than 10 in Xcode target, and you handle in your code to present the user that have >iOS 10 resources in compliance with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Both @GIJOW and @Shubham's answer is right. 
Just FYI, "Deployment target" means the minimum iOS version (if you're developing iOS app) that your app requires to be run on. For example, if you're building an app that only supports devices that are running iOS 9.1 and above, you can set your deployment target as 9.1, then any devices that run iOS 9.1+ will be able to run your app.